# remove namespace from childnode created element

Tags: c#, xml

In order to manipulate the dlls thats used inside of my VS project I have to update the reference that the dll is pointed to.  I do this via modifying the XML of the csproh (yes this works).

However, this time around I want to add the a SpecificVersion reference so `<SpecificVersion xmlns="">False</SpecificVersion>` however you cannot build using microsoft build engine when you have a custom xml namespace beneath the Reference element.  How do you remove the `xmlns=""` inside of the SpecificVersion node?

`<SpecificVersion xmlns="">False</SpecificVersion>`

```
XmlElement SpecificVersionElement = refNode.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("SpecificVersion");
SpecificVersionElement.InnerText = "False";
refNode.AppendChild(SpecificVersionElement);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Remarkable, like usual 30 seconds after I post something I figure it out.  And in this case it makes no sense.  By specifying a namespace, the createelement effectively removes the namespace.

```
XmlElement SpecificVersionElement =     refNode.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("SpecificVersion","http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
SpecificVersionElement.InnerText = "False";
refNode.AppendChild(SpecificVersionElement);
```

Of course this is probably hidden somewhere deep in a MSDN article

Comment: No, you're not *removing* the namespace - you're using the same namespace as is already the default for that element due to its parents. This is just namespace defaulting, which is part of XML itself.